# Azure Pipelines - Handling builds for Dependent downstream pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have more number of common upstream pipelines - pipleline-a, pipleline-b, pipeline-c, pipeline-d … each in its own repository - repository-a, repository-b, repository-c, repository-d…
My target pipeline, say pipeline-y in repository-y, has a dependency on these upstream pipelines artifacts and the target pipeline needs to build when there is a change to any of the upstream libraries and the corresponding upstream pipeline builds successfully.
In other words, target pipeline-y needs to be triggered if any of the upstream pipelines completed successfully due to changes in them (CI triggers for upstream libraries work fine in their own pipelines).

We currently achieved this, using the resources pipelines trigger in the target pipeline-y, as below:

**Upstream Pipeline - pipeline-a.yml**

```
trigger:

- repository-a*

steps

- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
  mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
  publishJUnitResults: false
  javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
  mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
  mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
  effectivePomSkip: false
  sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
  goals: 'package deploy'
```

**Target pipeline-y.yml resources section**

```
resources:
pipelines:

- pipeline: pipeline-a
  source: pipeline-a
  trigger:
  branches:
  - 'pipeline-a-v1*'
- pipeline: pipeline-b
  source: pipeline-b
  trigger:
  branches:
  - 'pipeline-b-v1*'
- pipeline: pipeline-c
  source: pipeline-c
  trigger:
  branches:
  - 'pipeline-c-v1*'
- pipeline: pipeline-d
  source: pipeline-d
  trigger:
  branches:
  - 'pipeline-d-v1*'
- pipeline: pipeline-e
  source: pipeline-e
  trigger:
  branches:
  - 'pipeline-e-v1*'
```

This works fine.

My question is, as we add more upstream common libraries, we have to update the resources section in the target downstream. When there are new versions of upstream libraries, we have to modify the version in resources-pipelines-pipiline-trigger - branches from “pipeline-a-v1” to “pipeline-a-v2”.

Is there a better way to do this? Can a variable be used in the resources-pipelines-pipeline-trigger - branches  - example **pipeline-a-$(version)** . Can version be derived using Build system variables as below:

I tried

variables:
version: $[replace(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], variables['Build.Repository.Name'], '')]

It did not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to dynamically specify resources in YAML.

A suggestion could be to use REST API hooks when new pipelines are added. Then trigger a program that generates new YAML for pipeline-y.yml.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.  You had mentioned it is not possible to dynamically specify the resoirces. Is it possible to specify a static value in the variables section

Comment: Please see below for what I tried.
```
variables:
  version: v1

resources:
pipelines:

- pipeline: pipeline-a
  source: pipeline-a
  trigger:
  branches:
  - 'pipeline-a-$(version)'
- pipeline: pipeline-b
  source: pipeline-b
  trigger:
  branches:
  - 'pipeline-b-$(version)
```
I tried this. I felt the behaviour is not consistent. Sometimes it seems to kick off the target pipeline when the source pipeline is manually triggered from the branch specified in the resources section. Sometimes it did not. Not sure if I am missing anything..

Comment: I believe everything in the resources section, including triggers, has to be constant.